# Finding the number of terms in an arithmetic sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-writing, proof-explanation, arithmetic, intuition

The formula for finding the length ( Number of terms ) in a finite arithmetic series is the following:

( The last term - First term ) / ( Common difference ) and finally adding 1.

What is the intuition or proof of this formula. How can we prove the above?

Comment: No, I don't think that's it. Do you mean the partial sums?

Comment: Let $d$ be the common difference and $a_1$ the first term and $a_n$ the last ($n$th) term. How many times do you need to add $d$ to $a_1$ to get to $a_n$? (Answer: $n-1$ times). So, $a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$. If you have everything else but $n$, you can solve this for $n$: $n=(a_n-a_1)/d + 1$.

Comment: Also, please fix the question to say "The formula for finding *the length* of a finite arithmetic sequence is..." instead of what you've written.

Comment: Difference between $n$-th term and first term include common difference $(n-1)$ times. One can visualize it as distance between something regular positioned like distance milestones. Then $n-1=\frac{a_n-a_1}{d}$, $n=\frac{a_n-a_1}{d}+1$.